# create a DEMO External Accessory application for IOS

Tags: android, ios, iphone, bluetooth, external-accessory

I want to make an IOS Demo application which will communicate with external devices using ios EA Framework

let say, I want to connect, exchange data with

1. external bluetooth device
2. external USB device

Is it possible to create a demo app without joining iOS MFI program?

or

Do I need to join with MFI first and then I will able to make demo app, because of hardware issue ?

If it is **possible to create** demo app without joining MFI, then **how to create a sample MFI device** and **what type of devices** can I use to communicate with iphone for demo purpose ?